# Django restrict foreignkey to records meeting a specific criteria

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-keys, django-orm

If I have a `Book` model which foreignkeys `Author`, how could I restrict what Authors are a valid foreignkey. For instance, if `Author` contains a `work_authored` field, I only want Books to be able to foreigkey Authors that have their `work_authored` field set to 'books' (verses other values  like 'articles', 'essays', 'plays').

My scenario (and TL; DR): I want my records to only be able to foreignkey other records that have a boolean field set to true.

I'm pretty sure this can be accomplished via Django's [object validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects), but that doesn't restrict the values in the Django admin's dropdown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to). You can set it as

```
class Book(Model):
    author = ForeignKey(AuthorModel, 
               limit_choices_to = { 'work_authered': 'books'}
              )
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested, and this also validates that the ForeignKey matches the criteria.